# Rotation ImageView in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, rotation, imageview

I'm trying to do old radio knob with rotation and that rotation is my problem. When mouse cursor is on the knob- everything is okey, however when mouse is leaving knob area everything is working badly. Here is my code for knob.
EDIT: I want to rotate knob just by moving left and right. Up and down moves don't interest me.
EDIT2: The problem does not occur only in knob area. I think it is dependent on
 cursor travel distance.

```
@FXML
void onFrequencyKnobMouseMove(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    double vX = (mouseEvent.getX() - deltaX);
    System.out.println("VX: " + vX);

    double rotation = frequencyKnob.getRotate() + vX;
    if(rotation > 180) rotation=180;
    if(rotation < -180) rotation=-180;
    frequencyKnob.setRotate(rotation);
    System.out.println("ROTATION: " + rotation);

    tuningLine.setLayoutX(rotation*1.33+250);

    deltaX = mouseEvent.getX();
    System.out.println("DELTAX: " + deltaX + "\n\n");
}


@FXML
void onFrequencyKnobMouseDown(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    deltaX = mouseEvent.getX();
    //System.out.println(deltaX);
}
```

FXML file

```xml
<ImageView fx:id="frequencyKnob" layoutX="856.0" layoutY="29.0" onMouseDragged="#onFrequencyKnobMouseMove" onMousePressed="#onFrequencyKnobMouseDown">
    <image>
        <Image url="@knob.png" />
    </image>
</ImageView>
```

[image: Knob rotating gif]

Comment: Which node do you add the event handlers to? (could you post the fxml snippet containing the relevant part of the fxml?)

Comment: Sure, in fxml is just ImageView with onMouseDragged and onMousePressed
<br/>
'<ImageView fx:id="frequencyKnob" layoutX="856.0" layoutY="29.0" onMouseDragged="#onFrequencyKnobMouseMove" onMousePressed="#onFrequencyKnobMouseDown">
         <image>
            <Image url="@knob.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added the handlers for the `MouseEvent`s to the `ImageView`. The coordinates available via this event object are in the coordinate system of the `ImageView` which is rotated. You should instead use coordinates in a coordinate system that remains unmodified. The simplest way would be using the `sceneX` property instead of the `x` property of `MouseEvent` or by transforming to the coordinate system of the parent.

#### Example

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Image image = new Image("knob.png");
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
    
    StackPane root = new StackPane(imageView);
    imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
    imageView.setFitWidth(300);
    imageView.setFitHeight(300);
    
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

    class MovedHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {
        
        double startX;
        double startRotate;
        
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            Point2D pt = imageView.localToParent(event.getX(), event.getY());
            double x = pt.getX();
            double newRotate = 3 * (x - startX) + startRotate;
            imageView.setRotate(newRotate);
        }
        
    }
    
    MovedHandler handler = new MovedHandler();
    imageView.setOnMouseDragged(handler);
    imageView.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
        Point2D pt = imageView.localToParent(event.getX(), event.getY());
        handler.startX = pt.getX();
        handler.startRotate = imageView.getRotate();
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but i can't implement this code into mine. Can i send u all of my code? Main.java: https://pastebin.com/enSZ49Xn || Controller.java: https://pastebin.com/FS8FKMLy || design.fxml: https://pastebin.com/tgKWFCyz

Comment: @ŁukaszBocian Shouldn't be too hard to adjust this (starting at your original code). Move the `startX`/ `startRotate` to the controller class, copy the implementations of the `handle` methods to the handler methods in your controller (and only those) and ajust the names: `handle->this`, `imageView->frequencyKnob`, `event->mouseEvent`